# Error: more than one instance of overloaded function "Datafrompeer" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I get the following error when compiling my code below:

> error:more than one instance of overloaded function "Datafrompeer"
>   matches the argument list

What can I do to resolve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <conio.h>

int  Datafrompeer(char* SERVER_ADDRESS_STR,int SERVER_PORT,FILE * fileptr)
{
}

void main()
{
    char* IPstr=NULL;  
    int Portnum; 
    FILE* SharedFilesList=NULL;

    Datafrompeer(IPstr,Portnum,SharedFilesList);
}
```

Comment: 1) It appears you are compiling C with a C++ compiler. 2) main returns int.

Comment: Apart from several warnings (uninitialised variable used, unreferenced formal parameter and must return a value) this compiles with VS2010 when `return 0` is added to `Datafrompeer`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: correct, i use visual studio 2010, i program in C but my file is *.cpp because i use the #include <WinSock2.h> otherwise i cant use the socket functions.

Comment: Is this really all of your code?

Comment: regarding to your warnings it all was done besides the initializing the  Pornum.which i can live with it i guess.

Comment: btw  there is another error somehow it doesnt identify the FILE type, it wrote me <error type> *fileptr

Comment: That `FILE` is not recognised is extraordinary. Does this, and only this, compile: `#include <stdio.h> int main() { FILE* SharedFilesList=NULL; return 0; }` ?

Comment: well the error regarding the error type filrptr appears in this line int  Datafrompeer(char* SERVER_ADDRESS_STR,int SERVER_PORT,FILE * fileptr)

Comment: there is no problem with the initalizing of this type only when i insert it to the funtion Datafrompeer